# checking elements at list of listes by python cod

Tags: python, list

I need to check if list contain any item in another list, i have the following lists:

A =  [[1,2,3] , [5,6,7], ...]

B = [ 1 , 8, 9]

I mean if 1 or 2 or at the first list at A list appear at B so append 'NF' at pred list and so on ,  as I write the following code:

```
if any(item in list for list in A for item in B):
  pred.append('NF')
else: 
  pred.append('F')
```

The problem is the result is always NF if the element is on the list or not.

The output:

```
['NF', 'F']
```

Comment: Looks like you have working code.  So what's the problem?

Comment: What's your question? What do you need help with?

Comment: my code not working correct as l want, the condition always true even it not!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your expected output. [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to get the outer loop outside of the `any` function?

```
A = [[1,2,3] , [5,6,7]]
B = [ 1 , 8, 9]

pred = []
for lst in A:
    if any(item in lst for item in B):
        pred.append('NF')
    else: 
        pred.append('F')
```

Output:

```
['NF', 'F']
```

As a one-liner:

```
pred = ['NF' if any(item in lst for item in B) else 'F' for lst in A]
```